# How to model a parent-tree design using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, hierarchical-data

My goal is to list out offices with parent offices in a tree format for a drop down list in a financial report. I am using .NET Core 2.1 with Entity Framework Core with data exposed via Web APIs.

The result I am after:

```
A
 A1
 A2
   A2A
B
 B1
  B1A
 B2
```

Here's my current model:

```cs
public class OfficeSymbol
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

I was trying to use `int Level` for how deep the child is nested.

I also tried the following, along with a `Cascade.NoAction`, but Entity Framework would not allow the key constraint:

```cs
public class OfficeSymbol
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Level { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public OfficeSymbol Parent { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public ICollection<OfficeSymbol> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I found the issue.  My object was already created and was trying to modify it from the upper code to the lower example.   I created a new project and was able to create the lower object on the fly.  So I believe either it can't modify an existing table to the lower object or there is a dependency elsewhere on another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately EF Core was not able to adjust an existing table from the first table sample to the second table sample.  I created a new object model and made it this way.

```
public class Office
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public OfficeSymbol Parent { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public ICollection<OfficeSymbol> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I am now going back and modifying my code to the new object.  Its mostly a find replace but I am modifying a few of the calls.

This builds correctly in SQL and make sure the parentId is nullable for root level objects.

Comment: When I get stuck on mappings I try to reverse engineer the DB.  Running this and comparing what gets generated with what you have could be beneficial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli